# Using docker pull & run to build dockerfile

Tags: docker, swagger

I'm learning how to use docker.

I want to deploy a microservice for swagger. I can do

```
docker pull schickling/swagger-ui
docker run -p 80:8080 -e API_URL=http://myapiurl/api.json swaggerapi/swagger-ui
```

To deploy it, I need a dockerfile i can run. 
How do i generate the dockerfile in a way I can run it with docker build ?

Comment: This isn't terribly clear - a Dockerfile for what?

Comment: You don't run docker files. You run docker images. You use dockerfiles to build docker images.  For instance, `swaggerapi/swagger-ui` is a docker image that you ran using `docker run ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original question asks for a Dockerfile, perhaps for some CI/CD workflow, so this answer addresses that requirement:

Create a very simple `Dockerfile` beginning with

```
FROM schickling/swagger-ui
```

Then from that directory run

```
$ docker build -t mycontainername .
```

Which can then be run:

```
$ docker run -p 80:8080 -e API_URL=http://myapiurl/api.json mycontainername
```

Comment: This doesn't really achieve anything though.  You may as well just run the original image directly.

Comment: The Op said they needed the Dockerfile, hence my approach. Perhaps they're constrained by a build or CI/CD system that assumes a Dockerfile is present.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the docker pull pulls the Dockerfile. The Dockerfile for swagger is on the docker repo for it if you wanted to edit it or customize it.
 (https://hub.docker.com/r/schickling/swagger-ui/~/dockerfile/)

That one should work with the build command. The build command builds the image, the run command turns the image into a container. The docker pull command should pull the image in. You don't need to run docker build for it as you should already have the image from the pull. You only need to do docker run.